# Overriding a method whose argument extends "generified" class

Tags: java, generics

I've just encountered an interesting problem related to Java generics. I'd like to use a concrete definition (DerivedPaginator) instead of "generified" definition (Paginator<Derived>). In order to do that, I have to change the method defined in the PaginatorTest. I've tried different combinations, but I still don't know how to do it.

Could you please help me with solving this puzzle?

```
interface Base {
}

interface Derived extends Base {
}

interface Paginator<T extends Base> {
}

interface DerivedPaginator extends Paginator<Derived> {
}

interface PaginatorTest<T extends Base> {
    // how to define this method so that it would accept DerivedPaginator?
    void check(Paginator<T> it);

    // nice try, but no cigar
    //<Y extends Paginator<T>> void check(Y it);
}

interface DerivedPaginatorTest extends PaginatorTest<Derived> {
    // this works fine
    //@Override
    //void check(Paginator<Derived> it);

    // but this doesn't
    @Override
    void check(DerivedPaginator it);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may declare

```
interface PaginatorTest<T extends Base, Y extends Paginator<T>> {
    void check(Y it);
}
```

and use it like

```
interface DerivedPaginatorTest extends PaginatorTest<Derived, DerivedPaginator> {
    @Override
    void check(DerivedPaginator it);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DerivedPaginator` extends `Paginator<Derived>`, but a `Paginator<Derived>` is not necessarily a `DerivedPaginator`. I could make some other class that implements `Paginator<Derived>` but not `DerivedPaginator`, so you cannot guarantee that that argument to `DerivedPaginatorTest .check()` is a `DerivedPaginator`. I'm not even sure why you have the interface `DerivedPaginator` which does not add anything to `Paginator<Derived>`. Anyway, if you need to be able to have `check()` method take something more specific than `Paginator<T>`, you need to generify over that something too, like Howard shows.